# For Which General Distributions Does This Inequality Hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a  random variable with mean $\mu$, where $0 < \mu < 1$.

Let  $X(n)$ be the sum of $n$ independent ,identically distributed, $X$ variables.

Under what conditions on $X$ , possibly dependent on $n$, is the following result true:

$$P[ X(n) \ge  (n+1)]  <  P[ X(n-1)\ge n]$$

For a simple illustration , if $X$ is discrete taking the values $0$ and $2$ with probabilities $0.7$ and $0.3$ respectively and $n=2$, the result is true as $0.09 < 0.3$.

The general question  arose from considering strategies for the players in the weaker of two  chess teams in a match.

Comment: It looks like if $X(n)=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$ then it suffices that $Y_n$ is right-skewed.

Comment: Thanks for this practically important generalisation.  I trust that, in due course, you will provide more mathematics or a reference to it.

Comment: Please note that the question has just been edited with "possibly dependent on n " replacing " independent of n".

Answer (score -1):

X having a Normal distribution with mu < (3-2^0.5)/(2-2^0.5) , implicitly n>=2 will do: consider z scores.

Alternatively X (negative)  exponential with Erlangian sums will do for appropriate mu.

Other examples may well be possible

Comment: I trust that, in due course, you will provide more mathematics or a reference to this answer.